# Library not loaded: @rpath/OneSignalExtension.framework/OneSignalExtension

Tags: xcode, flutter, onesignal

20-BED8-37C2EE174CFE/Runner.app/Frameworks/OneSignalExtension.framework/OneSignalExtension' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/OneSignalExtension.framework/OneSignalExtension' (no such file)
Library not loaded: @rpath/OneSignalExtension.framework/OneSignalExtension

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in my Flutter project version 2.10.3. I solved it by upgrading the project to version 3.3.10. I hope this information may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

Under Targets, click your app name. Include OneSignalExtension.xcframework in Framework, Library and Embedded Content.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine with 'OneSignalXCFramework', '3.4.0'